# Way to test alerts for backups?

Tags: sql-server, backup, alerts

We have some SQL Servers that are backed up using T-SQL and some that are using 3rd party backups (like Egnyte).

Is there a way to setup alerts inside SQL Server for that? I also need a way to test so we can be sure the alerts are working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about? SQL is just a query language used by all relational DBMS, it's not a DBMS product.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This is for Microsoft SQL Server.

For testing purpose, I downloaded a corrupt database backup file from [SQLSkills.com](https://www.sqlskills.com/sql-server-resources/sql-server-demos/)

Below is a quick script that will help you (obviously you can adapt the logic to do it dynamically for all your databases and send email in a nice HTML format) :

```
begin try
    BACKUP DATABASE broken TO DISK='D:\broken2005\broken2.bck'
    WITH CHECKSUM  --- very Important 
end try
begin catch

    declare @errorSubject char(100)
    declare @errorBody varchar(max)

    set @errorSubject = 'Full backup failed for database Broken on ' +@@servername
    set @errorBody = 'Full backup failed '+ char(10)+Cast(Error_Number() as nvarchar)+' - ['+Error_Message()+']'

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'databaseMail Profile',
    @recipients ='DBATeamEmailAddress@somecompany.com',
    @body = @errorBody,
    @subject = @errorSubject

end catch
```

Alternatively, you can use [SQL Server Backup solution from Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html).

Comment: This would only work on DBs that are done through MSSQL though, right? Would this run on ANY backup, even by a third party software?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to setup an alert is to base it off the error number that occurs for failed backups. That would be [error 3041](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2646329).

**To setup the Alert**

```
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_alert @name=N'Failed Backup Alert', 
        @message_id=3041, 
        @severity=0, 
        @enabled=1, 
        @delay_between_responses=0, 
        @include_event_description_in=1, 
        @job_id=N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_notification 
    @alert_name=N'Failed Backup Alert', 
    @operator_name=N'Me', --<<< set to operator for notification
    @notification_method = 1
GO
```

**Testing It**

To test it through SQL Server you can just try to backup a database that does not exist like this:

```
BACKUP DATABASE IDontExist TO DISK = N'C:\Temp\mydb.bak'
WITH INIT, CHECKSUM, COMPRESSION
```

To test with your third party application you will have to check with that vendor. I can tell you with something like [Idera's SQL Safe](https://www.idera.com/productssolutions/sqlserver/sqlsafebackup) you can likely create a backup policy for a temporary database, run the job once, set the database offline, and then try to run the job again. Idera's product has to see the database initially in order to setup the policy correctly.

I executed the above T-SQL on my local instance that I have the alert configured on three times and you can see the results below for the alert:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the work you put into this. And I think you're right about the third party stuff. That's what I was afraid of. I can't think of a way to setup something that would work in those cases, just too many unknowns to look for.

Comment: Ask the vendor, look in documentation (generally sections on common errors), check their forums (most have one somewhere)...